# No response to Rasa chatbot from Rasa action server

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I'm building a bot which ask questions and answers are free text. Because the logic goes like this "is the answer in list of accepted answers or is it anything else" I use action server to make this analysis.

Rasa version is **2.2**
Rasa-sdk version is **2.2**
I run both in separate docker containers.

Here is my *actions.py*

```
from typing import Any, Text, Dict, List
from rasa_sdk.events import SlotSet
from rasa_sdk import Action, Tracker
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher
from rasa_sdk.types import DomainDict

class kysymyksienTarkistus1(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_tarkista_kysymys_01"

    def run(
        self,
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:


        vastaus = tracker.latest_message["text"]
        # tarkistetaan onko vastaus oikein
        if vastaus == "puolikas":
            dispatcher.utter_message(response  = "utter_kysymys01_oikein")
            #dispatcher.utter_message(text=f"vastaus oikein")
            return []
        else:
            dispatcher.utter_message(response = "utter_kysymys01_vaarin")
            #dispatcher.utter_message(text=f"vastaus väärin")
            return []

class kysymyksienTarkistus2(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_tarkista_kysymys_02"

    def run(
        self,
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

        vastaus = tracker.latest_message["text"]
        # tarkistetaan onko vastaus oikein
        if vastaus == "100":
            dispatcher.utter_message(response  = "utter_kysymys02_oikein")
            return []
        else:
            dispatcher.utter_message(response = "utter_kysymys02_vaarin")
            return []

class kysymyksienTarkistus4(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_tarkista_kysymys_04"

    def run(
        self,
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

        vastaus = tracker.latest_message["text"]
        # tarkistetaan onko vastaus oikein
        if vastaus == "100":
            dispatcher.utter_message(response  = "utter_kysymys01_oikein")
            return []
        else:
            dispatcher.utter_message(response = "utter_kysymys04_vaarin")
            return []

class kysymyksienTarkistus5(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_tarkista_kysymys_04"

    def run(
        self,
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

        vastaus = tracker.latest_message["text"]
        # tarkistetaan onko vastaus oikein
        if vastaus == "100":
            dispatcher.utter_message(response  = "utter_kysymys01_oikein")
            return []
        else:
            dispatcher.utter_message(response = "utter_kysymys05_vaarin")
            return []
```

Here is debug from *shell*

```
2021-06-17 12:16:15 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.memoization  - There is a memorised next action 'action_tarkista_kysymys_01'
2021-06-17 12:16:15 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.ensemble  - Made prediction using user intent.
2021-06-17 12:16:15 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.ensemble  - Added `DefinePrevUserUtteredFeaturization(False)` event.
2021-06-17 12:16:15 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.ensemble  - Predicted next action using policy_0_AugmentedMemoizationPolicy.
2021-06-17 12:16:15 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Predicted next action 'action_tarkista_kysymys_01' with confidence 1.00.
2021-06-17 12:16:15 DEBUG    rasa.core.actions.action  - Calling action endpoint to run action 'action_tarkista_kysymys_01'.
2021-06-17 12:16:15 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Policy prediction ended with events '[<rasa.shared.core.events.DefinePrevUserUtteredFeaturization object at 0x7fde807a8190>]'.
2021-06-17 12:16:15 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Action 'action_tarkista_kysymys_01' ended with events '[BotUttered('None', {"elements": null, "quick_replies": null, "buttons": null, "attachment": null, "image": null, "custom": null}, {"response": "utter_kysymys01_oikein"}, 1623932175.3445601)]'.
2021-06-17 12:16:15 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.memoization  - Current tracker state:
[state 1] user intent: aloita | previous action name: action_listen
[state 2] user intent: aloita | previous action name: utter_kysymys_01
[state 3] user intent: vastaus01 | previous action name: action_listen
[state 4] user intent: vastaus01 | previous action name: action_tarkista_kysymys_01
2021-06-17 12:16:15 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.memoization  - There is a memorised next action 'action_listen'
2021-06-17 12:16:15 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.ensemble  - Predicted next action using policy_0_AugmentedMemoizationPolicy.
2021-06-17 12:16:15 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Predicted next action 'action_listen' with confidence 1.00.
2021-06-17 12:16:15 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Policy prediction ended with events '[]'.
2021-06-17 12:16:15 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Action 'action_listen' ended with events '[]'.
2021-06-17 12:16:15 DEBUG    rasa.core.lock_store  - Deleted lock for conversation '0e2913fd53434c9ab1b9d74f949c3808'.
```

and here is start of *strories*

```
version: "2.0"

stories:

- story: aloitus ja kysymys 01
  steps:
  - intent: aloita
  - action: utter_kysymys_01
  - intent: vastaus01
  - action: action_tarkista_kysymys_01

- story: lopetus 01
  steps:
  - action: utter_kysymys01_oikein
  - action: utter_lopetus
```

and here *domain.yml*

```
version: "2.0"

intents:
  - aloita
  - vastaus01
  - vastaus02
  - siirry_diaan_09
  - siirry_diaan_10

responses:  
  utter_kysymys_01:
  - text: "- Potilaalle on määrätty tyroksiinia 50 mikrogrammaa. Thyroxin tablettien vahvuus on 0,1 mg. Kuinka monta tablettia annat potilaalle?  \n- Montako tablettia otat purkista ja annat potilaalle?  \n- Kirjoita vastauksesi alle"
  utter_kysymys01_oikein:
  - text: Hienoa,  oikea vastaus! potilas saa oikean annoksen lääkettä.​
  utter_lopetus:
  - text: potilas saa oikean annoksen lääkettä.​
    image: "https://i.imgur.com/nGF1K8f.jpg"
  utter_kysymys01_vaarin:
  - text: "- Vastauksesi on väärin, lasketaan yhdessä uudestaan​."
  utter_kysymys_02:
  - text: "- Aloitetaan siitä, että muunnetaan ensin yksiköt samaan yksikköön​.  \n- Koska potilaalle on määrätty lääkeannos mikrogrammoissa, sinun täytyy muuttaa lääkepurkin vahvuutena oleva milligrammat samaan yksikköön eli mikrogrammoiksi (potilaalle oli määrätty 50 mcg)  \n- Purkissa olevan yhden tabletin vahvuus on? mikrogrammaa, kirjoita yksikönmuunnos vastauksesi alle."
  utter_kysymys02_oikein:
  - text: Hienoa, nyt on oikeat yksiköt laskua varten​.
    buttons:
    - title: " en tiedä"
      payload: "/siirry_diaan_09"
    - title: " tarkistetaan mikä olikaan potilaalle määrätty annos "
      payload: "/siirry_diaan_10"
    - title: " annetaan potilaalle 0,05 tablettia"
      payload: "/siirry_diaan_09"
  utter_dia_09:
  - text: Käydäänpä läpi miten yksikönmuunnokset tehdään.
  utter_dia_10:
  - text: "Käydäänpä läpi miten yksikönmuunnokset tehdään."
  utter_kysymys02_vaarin:
  - text: Väärin
  utter_kysymys_03:
  - text: Mikä olikaan potilaalle määrätty annos mikrogrammoina ? Tarvitset tämän tiedon pystyäksesi jatkamaan laskua​. kirjoita vastauksesi alle.
  utter_kysymys_04:
  - text: Eli jos purkissa oleva tabletti on 100 mikrogrammaa ja potilaalle on määrätty 50 mikrogrammaa. Eli kuinka monta tablettia annat?​
  utter_dia_12:
  - text: Kokeillaanpa laskea verranto -laskutavalla. X = kuinka monta tablettia pitää antaa​?
  utter_kysymys_05:
  - text: Lasketaan verranto  -laskutavalla​  /n- Kerrotaan ristiin 100 x X ja 50 x 1  /n- 100x = 50  /n- X = 50/100​  /n- X = 0,5 eli ___ tbl  /n- kirjoita vastauksesi alle​
  utter_kysymys05_vaarin:
  - text: Katso matikkapirkon video verranto -laskutapa​
  utter_kysymys04_vaarin:
  - text: lisää oikea teksti
  utter_dia_13:
  - text: tähän kanssa lisää


actions:
- action_tarkista_kysymys_01
- action_tarkista_kysymys_02
- action_tarkista_kysymys_04
- action_tarkista_kysymys_05

session_config:
  session_expiration_time: 60
  carry_over_slots_to_new_session: true
```

#rasa #rasa2.2 #actionserver

Comment: are the docker containers ports exposed so they could communicate with each other

Comment: and some of your text return in domain files are not enclosed with "", what channels are you using to get the response.